# constrain item in viewcontroller to item in navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, constraints, uisearchcontroller

UPDATE:

The search bar and segmented controller as posed in my original question look like this:
[image]

I tried adding the search bar as a child view controller of navigation controller in `viewDidLoad` of `BrowseViewController` (which is not a navigation controller)

```
[self.navigationController addChildViewController:_searchController];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:_searchController.searchBar];
_searchController.searchBar.frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;
[_searchController didMoveToParentViewController:self.navigationController];
```

Which renders this:
[image]

Everything on my view - the segmented control, the table - is gone.

UPDATE
I tried to constrain the segmented control to the navigation controller's view in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`:

```
         _segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
           NSLayoutConstraint *segWidthConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_segmentedControl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:350];

          NSLayoutConstraint *segHeightConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_segmentedControl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:32];

        NSLayoutConstraint *segLeadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_segmentedControl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.navigationController.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView.frame.origin.x];

        NSLayoutConstraint *segVerticalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_segmentedControl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.navigationController.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
        [_segmentedControl addConstraints:@[segWidthConst, segHeightConst, segLeadingConstraint, segVerticalConstraint]];
```

But I get this error:

```
US[5469:1553682] [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000295810 UISegmentedControl:0x7face152bc90.leading == UILayoutContainerView:0x7face141a600.leading   (inactive)>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2018-01-28 22:18:29.402296-0500 Leaflet-US[5469:1553682] *** Assertion failure in -[UISegmentedControl _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.33.6/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:734
Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
(null)
```

I have a UI search controller that I create and put inside my navigation controller inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
/*set appearance of search controller */
_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
_searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
_searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
[_searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
_searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
_searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
_searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleDefault;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

I also have a segmented control in my view. I want to align the leading constraint of the segmented control to the leading constraint of the search bar.

I tried doing so in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
_segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   NSLayoutConstraint *segWidthConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_segmentedControl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:350];

  NSLayoutConstraint *segHeightConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_segmentedControl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:32];

NSLayoutConstraint *segLeadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_segmentedControl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_searchController.searchBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *segVerticalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_segmentedControl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
[_segmentedControl addConstraints:@[segWidthConst, segHeightConst, segLeadingConstraint, segVerticalConstraint]];
```

However, doing so crashed the app:

```
[LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: 
        <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000486180 UISegmentedControl:0x7fa647e13620.leading == UISearchBar:0x7fa647f258f0.leading   (inactive)>
When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). 
This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. 
Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2018-01-28 18:21:14.589089-0500 Leaflet-US[3891:804350] *** Assertion failure in 
-[UISegmentedControl _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:
    mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.33.6/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:734
Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
```

When looking into view debugging, I saw that indeed the search bar is not a descendant of my view controller (unlike the segmented control, which is).

```
-UITabBarController 
 -UILayoutContainerView 
  -UitransitionView
   -UIViewControllerWrapperView 
    -UINavigationController
     -UILayoutContainerView
      -UINavigationTransitionView 
       -UIViewControllerWrapperView
        -BrowseViewController 
         -UIView 
          -UISegmentedControl
      -UINavigationBar
       -UIBarBackground
       -UINavigationBarContentView
        -UISearchBar
```

**How can I constrain my segmented control to my search bar if the search container view controller is itself wrapped inside a UINavigationController?**

Comment: What does you view hierarchy look like?

Comment: @dudeman thanks for pointing that out - I added it to my post

Comment: I tried to constrain segmented control to the navigation controller's view but I get `Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could try:

1) Only add `segWidthConst` and `segHeightConst` to the segmented control; and add the other two constraints to the navigation controller.

2) Get the `_searchController.searchBar`'s frame in relation to the navigation controller and then pin the segmented controller to the navigation controller's view using the frame's x as the constant.

Comment: I tried the first and got, `Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.` It seems I can't attempt the second unless I can successfully constrain the segmented control to navigation controller view?

Comment: Maybe try adding the constraints in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I'm adding the constraints in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` actually, but I can try viewWillAppear

Comment: I tried `viewWillAppear` instead and got same crash

Comment: One thing I just noticed is you're not adding the search controller as a child view controller of the navigation controller. So maybe try going through that process?

Comment: Instead of `self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;` I have, `[self.navigationController.view addSubview:_searchController.searchBar]` (and constraints in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`), I get the same crash

Comment: I meant something more along these lines: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW13

Comment: It appears that adding subview to navigation controller isn't supported :/

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should know is that you must add a constraint on the nearest ancestor view of the views  which are used to define it. So, obviously you should not add the leading constraint on the segment control. And according to the view hierarchy, you may try to add the constraint on UINavigationController’s UILayoutContainerView, because it seems to be the nearest ancestor view.